# MoM And YoY in same bar chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a dataset having three column Store, Month, Revenue. There are atleast 20 stores and over 50 months of revenue numbers. I have added a fiscal year column also.

I want to create a chart which asks user to input store number and fiscal year. my chart should have 12X2 bars showing MoM and YoY values. Will that be possible in SSRS.

Thank you in advance for any advice. I am using SSDT 2012

Comment: What exactly is your question? If it really is whether this is possible in SSRS, then yes, it certainly is possible. It might be easiest to make some changes to your dataset to provide some of the values as well. But I suspect you've got more questions. What hove you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck or what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to do it by adding 'FY' column in dataset and then dropping it to series group. earlier i had month names with year extension and that was causing the problem.